# Make tags bookmarking easier

Tags: feature-request, tags

I would just like to drag any tag to the "My Favorites" area and have it bookmarked that way. This would be a huge step in usability.

Comment: If you hover over a tag, in the upper left hand side, there's a star which will let you easily toggle between being favorited/ignored/normal. Perhaps this is the kind of functionality you're looking for? It can be easy to miss.

Comment: Thanks @FAE I didn't know that!

Comment: @FAE that is how your supposed to do it, but its harder on a tablet that has no hover capabilities. XD Thats what I'm usualy access I the site with. So the drag and drop would be useful in that regards.